# Setup different DNS for each SSID (dd-wrt)

Tags: dns, dd-wrt, ssid

I'd like to set up a different DNS for each SSID.
As far as I've gotten is creating virtual SSID in the DDWRT GUI. What I should do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just create as many VLANs as you like (three in the example below), and configure the DHCP configuration file as follows (this is for ISC DHCP server, the one I use at home for exactly this task)

```
 # guests
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.192;
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4;
}
# trusted
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 192.168.2.1;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.254.0;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
}
# trusted
 subnet 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     option routers 192.168.3.1;
     option subnet-mask 255.255.252.0;
     option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
}
```

Here I treat guests as guests, *i.e.* I do not grant them access to my internal DNS resolver but I allow them to contact Google's DNS resolvers, which is of course perfectly fine for surfing the Web.

On the other hand, I allow the members of the trusted VLANs to call upon my internal name resolver, so that they access other local hosts.

Comment: Is there any way I can target `ath0.1`, `ath0.2` & `ath0.3` specifically? Because I have no idea how thee thing with the addresses works?